# how to get a hidden file size in php

Tags: php

I am uploading image files in PHP but I found out that I was unable to get a file size of some images captured from one mobile device. I can get the file name but not the size so can anyone tell what likely will be the problem or how to fix it to be able to get the file size?
When I check the size in my system its size is in MB while other of my images are in KB.

```
<?php

if (isset($_FILES["file"]["name"][1]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {

    $fileext = ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "bif", "gif", "bmp"];
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($_FILES["file"]["name"]); $i++) {
        $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i];
        $type = $_FILES["file"]["type"][$i];
        $size = $_FILES["file"]["size"][$i];
        $path = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$i];

        $ext = end(explode('.', strtolower($name)));
        //checking file supported type
        if (in_array($ext, $fileext)) {
            echo $name . "<br>";
        } else {
            echo "file type not supported!";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: are you having problem UPLOADING the file or just calculating it size? if you get any error please submit it

Comment: i have problem calculating the size and as well can't upload that particular file

Comment: but i can upload other images captured from other device

Comment: "its size is in MB" -> it looks like a max size limit, check out about `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_filesize`

Comment: i think the problem is with the upload file size limits `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize`. Once check those in your php.ini file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### As for the file upload error:

You need to set the value of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini :

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

After modifying php.ini file(s), you need to restart your HTTP server to use new configuration.

### if you'r unable to access your php.ini you can try:

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '10M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 300);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

also incressing memory_limit might be usefull..